# The ConnectionString Property has not been initialised

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I run my code and I input the correct details the first time, the code works perfectly and logs the user in and passes through the id.

However, when I get the details incorrect, and I have to click login again then I get an error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialised

It gets to the `con.Open()` and then crashes without opening the database.

Any thoughts?

```
readonly SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=myPC;initial catalog=cafeDB;trusted_connection=true");
int loginChance = 3;

private void Btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int staffID;
    int account;

    string user = txt_username.Text;
    string pass = txt_password.Text;

    using (con)    // This will automatically close the connection when the brackets are exited
    {
        try
        {
            // THE CODE GETS TO HERE BEFORE BREAKING
            con.Open();

            // This SQL Command selects the data from the database
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, password FROM tbl_staff WHERE username = @user AND password = @pass", con))
            { 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);

                account = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());                        

                if (loginChance == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your out of login attempts");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (account == 1)
                    {
                        // SQL Statement to get staffID so it can be passed to the other users
                        using (SqlCommand cmdGetStaffID = new SqlCommand("SELECT staffID FROM tbl_staff WHERE username = @username", con))
                        {
                            cmdGetStaffID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
                            staffID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdGetStaffID.ExecuteScalar());
                        }

                        var menu = new Main_Menu
                                {
                                    StaffIDMenu = staffID,
                                    StaffUsernameMenu = user
                                };
                        menu.Show();

                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loginChance--;
                        lbl_Incorrect.Text = "Incorrect Username and Password\n" + loginChance + " chance(s) left";
                        lbl_Incorrect.Show();

                        this.txt_username.Clear();
                        this.txt_password.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception problem)
        {
            // This is error checking
            MessageBox.Show(problem.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must move SqlConnection to your method. `using (var con = new SqlConnection( ... )`

Comment: I'm using the SQL connection in the form load to do a connection test where the connection is opened and closed and I figure only making one instance of the connection is probably better

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). And it is just plain insecure to be storing plain-text passwords in a database.

Comment: This is only a project for school so im not too bothered about the plain text passwords but why shouldn't I use add with value. I saw that they're a better version of .add

Comment: You have several incorrect understandings, Add vs AddWithValue for instance (*read* the link provided); but also what `using` does.  See [using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) - it does a bit more than close the connection.  It disposes the connection object which means the next time you click the button, there is no connection.  And plaintext passwords are just wrong - even for school.

Comment: Ah thanks for the explaination I only thought it closes the connection i didn't realise it removes the object too although still surprised that c# didn't automatically create the instance again. Also the .Add seems much better I read that it had been depreciated so i assumed it was just worse but I'll definately be adding .Add instead now

Comment: `using` **will** create a new object if you use the full (correct) syntax as shown in the already provided documentation link.